# NoSuchElementException when reading from a pipe-delimited text file

Tags: java, tokenize, stringtokenizer

I am getting a `NoSuchElementException` when reading from a "|" (pipe) delimited text file.

I think this is the part that causes the error:

```java
public void readFromFile(String file)
{
    operas.clear(); //clear the ArrayList
    try
    {
        //Read while there is data
        Scanner input = new Scanner(new File(file)); //alternative to FileReader & BufferedReader
        String line = "";
        Opera music = null;
        StringTokenizer token = null;
        while(input.hasNextLine())
        {
            line = input.nextLine();
            music = new Opera(); // create an opera
            token = new StringTokenizer(line, "|");
            while (token.hasMoreElements())
            {
                music.setName(token.nextToken());
                music.setComposer(token.nextToken());
                music.setYear(Integer.parseInt(token.nextToken()));
                music.setCity(token.nextToken());
                music.setSynopsis(token.nextToken());
                music.setLink((token.nextToken()));
            }
        }
    ...
}
```

The error message:

[image: Error message]

Comment: Please properly indent your code, it is barely readable right now. Also, show the full error message including the relevant line it points to. It would also help if you show a full example, so with a `main` method that is triggering your issue.

Comment: Why did you choose `StringTokenizer` to parse a line in the file?  It's a legacy class and its usage is discouraged.

Answer (score 2):

You are checking, in the while loop, if there are more elements.
If so, it's guranteed that you have at least 1 element.
Yet, you are trying to read 6 elements during this loop...

Therefore, you get this error for a line which don't have 6 tokens.

You should check that you have enough tokens in order to make 6 "nextToken" calls.

I would suggest using a differnet functionality. Have you think about String splitting?

Something like:

```
    ...
    line = input.nextLine();
    String[] tokens = line.split("\\|");
    // Check that "tokens" is an array with 6 tokens as you expect...
    ...
```

Comment: Sure, edited. Didn't executed it, just wrote some pseudocode :)

Answer (score 0):

Aside from the issue with `StringTokenizer` which could be resolved by additionally checking if `token.hasNextToken()` before calling each setter in `Opera`, there are some other issues in the code which need to be refactored:

1. Use `try-with-resources` to ensure the `Scanner` instance is closed automatically
2. Fix declaration and usage of local variables
3. Use `String::split` method instead of `StringTokenizer`
4. Implement a helper method to build an instance of `Opera` from the array of `String`s
5. Populate `operas` with the read `Opera` *only* after the file has been successfully processed - in current implementation existing list is cleared at once and populated *afterwards*, that is, in case of I/O exception existing data are destroyed.

All the mentioned issues are addressed in the following sample:

```java
public void readFromFile(String file) {
    
    try (Scanner input = new Scanner(new File(file))) { // auto-close Scanner when done
        List<Opera> readOperas = new ArrayList<>();
        while(input.hasNextLine()) {
            String line = input.nextLine();
            
            String[] row = line.split("\\|");
            
            Opera music = buildOpera(row); // create an opera
            
            readOperas.add(music);
        }
        operas.clear();
        operas.addAll(readOperas);
    } catch (IOException ioex) {
        // log the exception
    }
}
static Opera buildOpera(String ... row) {
    Opera opera = new Opera();

    if (row.length > 0) { opera.setName(row[0]); }
    if (row.length > 1) { opera.setComposer(row[1]); }
    if (row.length > 2) { opera.setYear(Integer.parseInt(row[2])); }
    if (row.length > 3) { opera.setCity(row[3]); }
    if (row.length > 4) { opera.setSynopsis(row[4]); }
    if (row.length > 5) { opera.setLink(row[5]); }

    return opera;
}
```

---

Using Java Stream API along with `java.nio` classes would result in the following implementation (reusing method `buildOpera`):

```java
public void readFromFile(String file) {
    try {
        List<Opera> readOperas = Files.lines(Path.of(inputFileName)) // get stream of lines from the input file
             .map(s -> s.split("\\|"))  // split a line into columns, get Stream<String[]>
             .filter(row -> row.length == 6) // make sure a row contains full data
             .map(MyClass::buildOpera)
             .collect(Collectors.toList());
        operas.clear();
        operas.addAll(readOperas);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        // log IO exception
    }
}
```